# Is Native Kotlin FaceDetector can't be used anymore?

Tags: kotlin, face-detection

I'm looking for a way to detect faces in an ImageView or Bitmap using Kotlin. I initially used ML Kit, which worked perfectly, but it adds over 40MB to the APK file and requires a minimum SDK of 26, making it unavailable to some of my clients

I use this MLKit Gradle to do it
`implementation 'com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.1.5'`

So I tried some of code like FaceDetector like this

```
val img = (imgView.getDrawable() as BitmapDrawable).bitmap

val MAX_FACES = 10
val faceDetector = FaceDetector(img.width, img.height, MAX_FACES)
val faces = arrayOfNulls<FaceDetector.Face>(MAX_FACES)
val faceCount = faceDetector.findFaces(img, faces)

Log.e("HK", "faceCount " + faceCount)
```

No matter how clear the face is set in the ImageView, the face count always returns 0. Does anyone know why this happens, and is there any alternative solution?

EDIT:
Nevermind, this gradle is more than enough and it only add 1 MB

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:17.1.0'
```